# I am trying to show doc/docx file using WebView in android

Tags: android, webview, docx

I am trying open a base64 string in WebView which is actually a doc/docx.

I have tried many ways, I don't wanna end up having paid library.

Here is my code. Please suggest...!

```
    String lBase64Str =
              Base64.encodeToString(lBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
      URL lUrl = new URL(lBase64Str);
     lWebView.loadUrl(lUrl.toString());

lWebView.loadData(lBase64Str,"text/html","base64");
```

Comment: `WebView` has no built-in ability to display Microsoft document formats, PDFs, or anything other than ordinary Web content (HTML/CSS/JS).

Comment: @CommonsWare There must be a way to achieve this.. other than WebView or anything else?

Comment: Use `ACTION_VIEW` and see if the device has a viewer app installed. Or, use a library. Or, have your server convert the document to HTML/CSS/JS and display that with a `WebView`. Or, have your server convert the document to PDF and display that with a PDF library.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't want to share the document on any of the viewer apps I want to open it in  my app only.

Comment: Then, use a library. Or, have your server convert the document to HTML/CSS/JS and display that with a WebView. Or, have your server convert the document to PDF and display that with a PDF library.